# Must an LCD panel meet specific requirements to support a higher refresh rate?

Tags: lcd, led-driver, frequency-response

Newer LCDs can refresh the screen at 120Hz or higher. The driver circuitry for the panel is responsible for pushing frames to the panel at a given rate, but are there any particulars of the LCD panel itself that factor into achieving the higher refresh rate? Are there, for instance, any special materials, construction, or circuitry of the panel needed to correctly respond to a higher refresh rate? In other words, is it theoretically possible to drive a panel over its specified refresh rate using another driver board, assuming all interfacing requirements are identical?

Comment: As far as I know LCDs are refreshed in the 60 Hz to a couple of hundred hertz frame rate - enough to give a flicker-free image. Are you thinking of the display multiplexing circuitry or the data transmission to the display such as HDMI? Please clarify in your question rather than in the comments.

Comment: Hmmm. So there's more circuitry in the LCD?

Comment: Is it clearer now?

Comment: No. LCDs are used in everything from digital thermometers to large screen displays. It's not clear what you are talking about, where the frame buffer is in your scheme of things, where the 120 MHz is and why you are asking. Why have you got the question tagged "led-driver"? What do you hope to achieve by driving an LCD beyond its ratings?

Comment: I think he's asking for instance with two similar size monitors, one a standard 60hz, and one a high performance 144hz gaming monitor, whether the physical LCD/OLED/whatever panel is superior in some necessary way on the 144hz gaming monitor, or if it is mechanically the same and driven in a superior way.

Comment: @KH Thank you. Precisely what I mean.

Comment: @Transistor The LED driver tag is a bad one. LCD driver is what I meant to chose. Anyways, modern LCD do have LED drivers.

Comment: @KH  That's quite a career change from mayor of Boston to an engineer. 

Comment: @user148298 I am not familiar with the relevant memes.  I am but a humble electrician and enjoy learning about engineering as a hobby.

Comment: @KH  Kevin White was the mayor of Boston from 1968 to 1984.  I thought you would have heard of him at least in passing since you have the same first and last name.

Comment: @user148298 White does not start in an H.  I think you clicked onto the wrong profile somewhere.  Mine is blank and doesn't even link anywhere.  I'm nowhere near good enough to be EE.SE famous.

Comment: I thought you were the same person who edited the question. Doh!

Comment: By the way a cursory google search on replacement panels seems to indicate that panels in general are typically replaced with devices specifically designed to imitate the original and are compatible with a limited number of models.  There may be a company somewhere that is binning panels (Make 1000000 and separate the random result into groups by quality and use them for different products/purposes) and in some cases a device can be used for a higher purpose than its bin was intended for.

Comment: An example would be early graphics cards where they manufactured an 8 core chip and if one core tested bad, sold it as a 6 or 4 core chip.  To produce adequate volume for the 4 core models they sometimes used fully functional 8 core chips simply disabled.   Some users were able to reconfigure their chip to enable the extra cores with the result being either the device worked like it's more expensive counterpart, or fried itself because there was in fact a bad core.

Comment: @KH Ah ha! You're on to my reason for this question!  The cost of replacing a 2017 iPad Pro screen is $400, but its only around $200 for the older 2015 model . The specifications are identical, except that the 2017 refreshes the display up to 120Hz, the screen has higher nits and different connectors. I figured it might be possible to adapt the older screen to work on a newer model. But who am I to be so clever? If it could be done, I'm sure the AliExpress would be selling such a solution.

Comment: The problem with Aliexpress was that with many of the sellers, if they did find such a solution, they would simply sell it as if it were the normal 144hz product.  This kind of behaviour would account for a portion of the aliexpress knockoffs that don't quite live up to the original product.

Comment: @KH  I am planning on trying it at some point, but I want to try my hand at converting one of the newer MacBook panels to work with an A1502 (2013-2014 MacBook Pro).  The A1502 uses the same eDp protocol, same resolution, but uses a 30pin connector instead of 40pin and different glass face. The circuitry is straightforward, but  finding an LCD glass or having one made is the real challenge. Also, I am hoping the glass can be glued on directly without removing the preexisting one.

Comment: Hmm.  Having a 40 vs 30 pin connector would likely indicate fundamentally different drive circuitry.  It sounds like a very hopeful project at best to be honest.

Comment: @KH Nah, the 30pin and 40pin are just eDP standards. Most the pins on the 40pin are either duplicates, ground or unused.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The driver circuitry for the panel is responsible for pushing frames to the panel at a given rate, but are there any particulars of the LCD panel itself that factor into achieving the higher refresh rate?

Since the panels are big 2D arrays of pixels addressed similarly to a DRAM cell, the LCD itself must be able to clock at the pixel rate you're driving.  If its internal capacitances are too large or its transistors too slow, there won't be time for the pixel to update before the next value is driven into the array.

In addition, since the pixel array is essentially an optical digital to analog converter, there are also sampling rate concerns.  Driving the array at a higher pixel rate is equivalent to increasing the temporal sampling rate driving each pixel.  Increasing the update rate while keeping the analog impulse response of each pixel unchanged is equivalent to increasing the sampling rate of a DAC without also adjusting the analog bandwidth of the electronics it is driving.  Eventually your analog bandwidth falls far enough below the Nyquist (folding) frequency that although you are updating the pixels more frequently, no new information is actually being modulated onto the pixel output because it simply cannot respond faster (even if the array itself can physically sustain the pixel rate).

So yes, there are two factors.  The array must be able to shift values at the pixel rate you've selected and the pixels themselves must be fast enough (have sufficient bandwidth) that the faster refresh rate actually does something.

> In other words, is it theoretically possible to drive a panel over its specified refresh rate using another driver board, assuming all interfacing requirements are identical?

Yes, and you do occasionally see manufacturers offering displays at refresh rates above the nominal spec value for the panel they are using.

Comment: You answer is inline with what I am thinking. Your last response is especially insightful. Assuming two identical panels with different spec values are being manufactured around the same time, it really makes little sense to have two different BOMs. The economies of scale gained in consolidating materials usually far exceeds the trivial savings gained from using slower device A over faster device B. The exception is Apple who doesn't mind paying up just to change it up.